# $\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!}\times (-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3}=(-3)^n.$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

How to prove this identity. 
I think this is a multinomial identity but have no clue how to prove this is true.
Thanks to the comment, since $(-1)^{n1-n2+n3} = (-1)^{n1+n2+n3} = (-1)^n$, is it valid to move $(-1)^{n1-n2+n3}$ term to the right hand side?
$$
\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!}\times (-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3}=(-3)^n.
$$
Then we can simply prove:
$$ 
\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!} = 3
$$

However, why is this true? Is there a combinatoric proof for this identity?

Comment: NB $(-1)^{n_1+n_2+n_3}=(-1)^n$.

Comment: Note that $(-1)^{-n}=(-1)^n$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it's not (n1+n2+n3) but (n1-n2+n3) as the power of (-1)

Comment: @HerrGünther That makes no odds....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. I see the reasoning, but why would this identity be true? Is there any combinatoric methodology behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Yes, it's a multinomial identity. Now, $n_1,n_2$ and $n_3$ are three terms, so it ought to be a good idea to write $-3$ as a sum of three numbers. And the summand (the term behind $\sum$) is symmetric in the $n_i$, so it might be a good idea to let the three numbers that $-3$ is a sum of be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the mistake I make here is to look at the equation and start to simplify both sides right away. Then it's easy to stuck with why the following is true.
$$
\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!} = 3$$
The key here is to use the multinomial theorem: 
$$
(x_1+x_2+x_3)^{n}= \sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \frac{n!}{n_1 ! n_2 ! n_3 !} (x_1)^{n_1} (x_2)^{n_2} (x_3)^{n_3}
$$
Thanks to @LordSharktheUnknown, we know that $$(-1)^n = (-1)^{-n}$$
We can just use plug in -1 as the value for x1, x2 and x3, the we will find the LHS becomes  $-3^n$ , and RHS is simply $$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \frac{n!}{n_1 ! n_2 ! n_3 !} (-1)^{n_1} (-1)^{n_2} (-1)^{n_3}$$ 
Replace $-1^{n_2}$ with $-1^{-n_2}$, we got our answer.
$$
(-3)^{n}= \sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \frac{n!}{n_1 ! n_2 ! n_3 !} (-1)^{n_1} (-1)^{-n_2} (-1)^{n_3}
$$
which, is equivalent to:
$$
(-3)^{n}= \sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n} \frac{n!}{n_1 ! n_2 ! n_3 !} (-1)^{n_1-n_2+n_3} 
$$